# postgresql alter table add column serial with sort values on created_at

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have user tables and now I want to add one serial column `cid`:

user:

```
 id    | username | email           | createdAt
-------------------------------------------------
"uuid" | "abc"    | "abc@gmail.com" | '2017-01-01'
"uuid" | "abc"    | "abc@gmail.com" | '2017-02-01'
"uuid" | "abc"    | "abc@gmail.com" | '2017-03-01'
```

I want to add a column cid with values like `serial` but not primary key

```
  id   |username|     email       | createdAt    | cid
-------------------------------------------------------
"uuid" | "abc"  | "abc@gmail.com" | '2017-01-01' |  1
"uuid" | "abc"  | "abc@gmail.com" | '2017-02-01' |  2
"uuid" | "abc"  | "abc@gmail.com" | '2017-03-01' |  3
...
```

What I tried:

```
alter table user add column cid serial not null;
```

but it generates:

```
  id   |username|     email       | createdAt    | cid
-------------------------------------------------------
"uuid" | "abc"  | "abc@gmail.com" | '2017-01-01' | 4
"uuid" | "abc"  | "abc@gmail.com" | '2017-02-01' | 7
"uuid" | "abc"  | "abc@gmail.com" | '2017-03-01' | 3
....
```

can I do something like:

```
alter table user add column cid serial not null order by createdAt
```

So that it can generate the expected result which is `cid` sequential values with order by `createdAt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why add it to the table?  You can just do:

```
select u.*, row_number() over (order by u.createdAt) as seqnum
from user u;
```

If you have an index on `user(createdAt)`, then this should take advantage of the index.

If you have a unique column on the table, you can do an update:

update user u
    set cid = uu.seqnum
    from (select u.*, row_number() over (order by u.createdAt) as seqnum
          from user u
         ) uu
         on u.uuid = uu.uuid

Comment: Thank you for giving a quick answer.....yes I have to add the column as my id column is an uuid so need a seperate column which has a sequential number

Comment: I also tried  `update user set cid =  row_number() over (order by user.createdAt)` but throwing error